# dynamics ax 2012: Change RowState from Edit to Selected

Tags: rowstate, dynamics-ax-2012

In AXGridView, I want to change the row state of selected row, which is in edit mode to selected mode.

This needs to happen on clicking an external button.

I tried the following ways:

1. Updated the RowState of the selected Row to DataControlRowState.Selected
2. Updated the GridView's EditIndex to -1

None of them worked :(.

Surprisingly, even the e.cancel = true statement in RowEditing event handler is also not changed the row state. :(

I'm new to AX, may be its basic. Please tell me the solutiion/ work around.

Answer (score 0):

Since my only experience is from AX 2009, this might be invalid for AX 2012. If it works in the same way as with EP for AX 2009, then you should be able to get the row and run EndEdit(). Have a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc624200(v=ax.50).aspx